# Running Access Macro shortcut from batch file

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, macros

I am trying to make a little script that copies an Access macro shortcut to a users desktop, and after that runs the shortcut. But I can't seem to get the last part done right, so I hope someone in here can help.

My bacth file looks like this:

```
rem @ECHO off
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a IN ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\control\nls\language" /v InstallLanguage') DO (
    SET answer=%%a
) 
IF %answer%==0406 (
    GOTO :DANSK
) ELSE (
    GOTO :OTHER
)

:DANSK

xcopy "\\srv-prod\Produktion\Access\shortcut\." "%userprofile%\Skrivebord\" /y

start "%userprofile%\Skrivebord\Start operation i DS HalC_32bit.accde.MAM"

GOTO :END

:OTHER
xcopy "\\srv-prod\Produktion\Access\shortcut\." "%userprofile%\desktop\" /y
GOTO :END

:END
rem pause
```

With start I just get another command prompt and nothing else. What am I doing wrong, cause if I type the path into a command prompt, it will start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument for `start` is a *window title* not the path so:

```
start "" "%userprofile%\Skrivebord\Start operation i DS HalC_32bit.accde.MAM"
```